# Gradle build FAILD in Android SDK canary 4

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when i try to build my project on the regular Android SDK edition it builds with no problems but when i use Android SDK preview Edition **Canary 4**  i get this error

```
>       Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio Preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha2/gradle-3.0.0-alpha2.pom
>         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio Preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha2/gradle-3.0.0-alpha2.jar
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha2/gradle-3.0.0-alpha2.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha2/gradle-3.0.0-alpha2.jar
>     Required by:
>         project :
```

Comment: Use stable version .

Answer (score 0):

You try to use new version of Gradle. In order to that, you should change `distributionUrl` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip`in gradle-wrapper.properties file (project/gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties)

Answer (score 0):

updating the distributionUrl and the gradle to

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'

might help you.